# Transition not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My goal is that given a value in seconds(resp_time), I want to create a counter in anticlock direction that would end once resp_time becomes 0.

I am following this tutorial: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1096355 to create a polar clock. But I need the arc to decrease as in go anti-clockwise. I tried updating the endAngle value for the same, but it doesn't seem to work.
Here's my code:

```
var width = 960,
    height = 800,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 1.9,
    spacing = .09;

var resp_time = 61;

var rh = parseInt(resp_time/3600), rm = parseInt((resp_time- rh*3600)/60), rs = parseInt((resp_time- rh*3600 - rm*60)%60);

var color = d3.scale.linear()
    .range(["hsl(-180,50%,50%)", "hsl(180,50%,50%)"])
    .interpolate(interpolateHsl);

var t; 

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(0)
    .endAngle(function(d) { return d.value * 2 * Math.PI; })
    .innerRadius(function(d) { return d.index * radius; })
    .outerRadius(function(d) { return (d.index + spacing) * radius; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var field = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(fields)
  .enter().append("g");

field.append("path");

field.append("text");

d3.transition().duration(0).each(tick);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");

function tick() {
  field = field
      .each(function(d) { this._value = d.value; })
      .data(fields)
      .each(function(d) { d.previousValue = this._value; });

  field.select("path")
    .transition()
      .ease("elastic")
      .attrTween("d", arcTween)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.value); });

  field.select("text")
      .attr("dy", function(d) { return d.value < .5 ? "-.5em" : "1em"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.text; })
    .transition()
      .ease("elastic")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "rotate(" + 360 * d.value + ")"
            + "translate(0," + -(d.index + spacing / 2) * radius + ")"
            + "rotate(" + (d.value < .5 ? -90 : 90) + ")"
      });

    if (resp_time > 0)
    {
        resp_time = resp_time - 1;
        rh = parseInt(resp_time/3600), rm = parseInt((resp_time- rh*3600)/60), rs = parseInt((resp_time- rh*3600 - rm*60)%60);
        t = setTimeout(tick, 1000);
    }

}

function arcTween(d) {
  console.log(d);
  var i = d3.interpolateNumber(d.previousValue, d.value);
  return function(t) { d.value = i(t); return arc(d); };
}


function fields() {
  console.log(rs);
  return [
    {index: .3, text: rs+"s", value: rs},
    {index: .2, text: rm+"m", value: rm},
    {index: .1, text: rh+"h", value: rh}
  ];
}

function interpolateHsl(a, b) {
  var i = d3.interpolateString(a, b);
  return function(t) {
    return d3.hsl(i(t));
  };
}
```

This is just resulting in 3 static concentric circles(since I'm plotting only the minute, seconds and hours) with no transition.

I'm not sure how to proceed from here. What change should I make to get it working? Please help me out.

Comment: `d.value = i(t); return arc(d);` relies on `t` being a meaningful value, but your `t = setTimeout(tick, 1000)` isn't setting it to anything meaningful. (`setTimeout` returns an arbitrary number identifying the timeout, which is only useful in case you wanted to cancel a timeout before it occurs, as in `clearTimeout(t)`). Maybe you mean to call `i(resp_time)`? (not totally sure if that's right either, bc I didn't get too familiar with your code, but it's gotta be something that depends on `resp_time`).

Comment: I had a clearTimeout before. I forgot to remove it. But, if I call i(resp_time), how will I calculate and update values for hour, second and minutes?

Comment: Sorry, I now see that 't' was defined through the function returned by arcTween, so the setTimeout 't' was not the issue. Not sure what the right answer is bc I'm not familiar with the d3 arc module. If you had a jsfiddle set up it would help.

Answer (score 0):

`d.value` in this code should be in the range [0, 1], so you need to divide by the maximum values in the fields generator:

```
function fields() {
  console.log(rs);
  return [
    {index: .3, text: rs+"s", value: rs/60},
    {index: .2, text: rm+"m", value: rm/60},
    {index: .1, text: rh+"h", value: rh/24}
  ];
}
```

I noticed this because `console.log(rs)` was printing out values in the range of [0, 60] whereas `arc.endAngle` [expects a radian value](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#arc_endAngle). If you substitute [0, 60] with the endAngle provider in the code, you get an over wound clock hand.

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(0)
    .endAngle(function(d) { return d.value * 2 * Math.PI; })
```

```js
var width = 960,
    height = 800,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 1.9,
    spacing = .09;

var resp_time = 61;

var rh = parseInt(resp_time/3600), rm = parseInt((resp_time- rh*3600)/60), rs = parseInt((resp_time- rh*3600 - rm*60)%60);

var color = d3.scale.linear()
    .range(["hsl(-180,50%,50%)", "hsl(180,50%,50%)"])
    .interpolate(interpolateHsl);

var t; 

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(0)
    .endAngle(function(d) { return d.value * 2 * Math.PI; })
    .innerRadius(function(d) { return d.index * radius; })
    .outerRadius(function(d) { return (d.index + spacing) * radius; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var field = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(fields)
  .enter().append("g");

field.append("path");

field.append("text");

d3.transition().duration(0).each(tick);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");

function tick() {
  field = field
      .each(function(d) { this._value = d.value; })
      .data(fields)
      .each(function(d) { d.previousValue = this._value; });

  field.select("path")
    .transition()
      .ease("elastic")
      .attrTween("d", arcTween)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.value); });

  field.select("text")
      .attr("dy", function(d) { return d.value < .5 ? "-.5em" : "1em"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.text; })
    .transition()
      .ease("elastic")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "rotate(" + 360 * d.value + ")"
            + "translate(0," + -(d.index + spacing / 2) * radius + ")"
            + "rotate(" + (d.value < .5 ? -90 : 90) + ")"
      });

    if (resp_time > 0)
    {
        resp_time = resp_time - 1;
        rh = parseInt(resp_time/3600), rm = parseInt((resp_time- rh*3600)/60), rs = parseInt((resp_time- rh*3600 - rm*60)%60);
        t = setTimeout(tick, 1000);
    }

}

function arcTween(d) {
  console.log(d);
  var i = d3.interpolateNumber(d.previousValue, d.value);
  return function(t) { d.value = i(t); return arc(d); };
}


function fields() {
  console.log(rs);
  return [
    {index: .3, text: rs+"s", value: rs/60},
    {index: .2, text: rm+"m", value: rm/60},
    {index: .1, text: rh+"h", value: rh/24}
  ];
}

function interpolateHsl(a, b) {
  var i = d3.interpolateString(a, b);
  return function(t) {
    return d3.hsl(i(t));
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```